# Configuring a MySQL server for managing thousands of tables

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We currently have AWS RDS MySQL server instance with thousands of tables (approximately 350k). This is because we use an schema per customer approach, where every customer has his own database.

Over time, we notice a degradation of performance and accordingly with aws suggestion in [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.MySQLStorage) we should adjust **table_open_cache** and **table_definition_cache** parameters.

How can I increase this parameters while being ensuring that we don't run out of memory?

The db instance has 8GB of RAM of which 2GB free most of the time. Right now both of table_open_cache and table_definition_cache are set to 400.

Result of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`

```
Variable_name | Value
Aborted_clients | 10
Aborted_connects | 21
Acl_cache_items_count | 1
AuroraDb_commits | 2036080
AuroraDb_commit_latency | 10474020840
AuroraDb_ddl_stmt_duration | 967597256
AuroraDb_select_stmt_duration | 2137359090413
AuroraDb_insert_stmt_duration | 2885053612
AuroraDb_update_stmt_duration | 1007422326
AuroraDb_delete_stmt_duration | 288692100
Aurora_binlog_io_cache_allocated | 0
Aurora_binlog_io_cache_read_requests | 0
Aurora_binlog_io_cache_reads | 0
Aurora_caspian_buf_pool_resize_completed | 0
Aurora_caspian_buf_pool_resize_rejected | 0
Aurora_caspian_buf_pool_resize_requested | 0
Aurora_enhanced_binlog | DISABLED
Aurora_enhanced_binlog_earliest_continuous_file | 
Aurora_external_connection_count | 12
Aurora_fast_insert_cache_hits | 0
Aurora_fast_insert_cache_misses | 235634
Aurora_last_allocated_lsn_for_replication | 7104504239
Aurora_thread_pool_thread_count | 4
Aurora_tmz_version | 2023c
Binlog_cache_disk_use | 0
Binlog_cache_use | 0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use | 0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use | 0
Bytes_received | 16391884265
Bytes_sent | 269785114378
Com_admin_commands | 17910
Com_assign_to_keycache | 0
Com_alter_db | 0
Com_alter_event | 0
Com_alter_function | 0
Com_alter_instance | 0
Com_alter_procedure | 0
Com_alter_resource_group | 0
Com_alter_server | 0
Com_alter_table | 10526
Com_alter_tablespace | 0
Com_alter_user | 1
Com_alter_user_default_role | 0
Com_analyze | 0
Com_begin | 2
Com_binlog | 0
Com_call_procedure | 0
Com_change_db | 1351785
Com_change_master | 0
Com_change_repl_filter | 0
Com_change_replication_source | 0
Com_check | 0
Com_checksum | 0
Com_clone | 0
Com_commit | 88248
Com_create_db | 3
Com_create_event | 0
Com_create_function | 18
Com_create_index | 0
Com_create_procedure | 0
Com_create_role | 0
Com_create_server | 0
Com_create_table | 396
Com_create_resource_group | 0
Com_create_trigger | 0
Com_create_udf | 0
Com_create_user | 0
Com_create_view | 176
Com_create_spatial_reference_system | 0
Com_dealloc_sql | 0
Com_delete | 283314
Com_delete_multi | 0
Com_do | 0
Com_drop_db | 2
Com_drop_event | 0
Com_drop_function | 0
Com_drop_index | 0
Com_drop_procedure | 0
Com_drop_resource_group | 0
Com_drop_role | 0
Com_drop_server | 0
Com_drop_spatial_reference_system | 0
Com_drop_table | 224
Com_drop_trigger | 0
Com_drop_user | 0
Com_drop_view | 88
Com_empty_query | 0
Com_execute_sql | 0
Com_explain_other | 0
Com_flush | 1087
Com_get_diagnostics | 0
Com_grant | 0
Com_grant_roles | 0
Com_ha_close | 0
Com_ha_open | 0
Com_ha_read | 0
Com_help | 0
Com_import | 0
Com_insert | 1178206
Com_insert_select | 232155
Com_install_component | 0
Com_install_plugin | 0
Com_kill | 0
Com_load | 0
Com_lock_instance | 0
Com_lock_tables | 15504
Com_optimize | 0
Com_preload_keys | 0
Com_prepare_sql | 0
Com_purge | 0
Com_purge_before_date | 589
Com_release_savepoint | 0
Com_rename_table | 0
Com_rename_user | 0
Com_repair | 0
Com_replace | 335
Com_replace_select | 0
Com_reset | 0
Com_resignal | 0
Com_restart | 0
Com_revoke | 0
Com_revoke_all | 0
Com_revoke_roles | 0
Com_rollback | 0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint | 0
Com_savepoint | 0
Com_select | 40630993
Com_set_option | 9437548
Com_set_password | 0
Com_set_resource_group | 0
Com_set_role | 0
Com_signal | 0
Com_show_binlog_events | 0
Com_show_binlogs | 2
Com_show_charsets | 0
Com_show_collations | 0
Com_show_create_db | 5168
Com_show_create_event | 0
Com_show_create_func | 28560
Com_show_create_proc | 0
Com_show_create_table | 1405977
Com_show_create_trigger | 0
Com_show_databases | 11
Com_show_engine_logs | 0
Com_show_engine_mutex | 0
Com_show_engine_status | 0
Com_show_events | 0
Com_show_errors | 0
Com_show_fields | 703350
Com_show_function_code | 0
Com_show_function_status | 5168
Com_show_grants | 2
Com_show_keys | 272
Com_show_master_status | 3
Com_show_open_tables | 9
Com_show_plugins | 0
Com_show_privileges | 0
Com_show_procedure_code | 0
Com_show_procedure_status | 2924
Com_show_processlist | 0
Com_show_profile | 0
Com_show_profiles | 0
Com_show_relaylog_events | 0
Com_show_replicas | 0
Com_show_slave_hosts | 0
Com_show_replica_status | 3
Com_show_slave_status | 3
Com_show_status | 6030
Com_show_storage_engines | 0
Com_show_table_status | 702986
Com_show_tables | 35096
Com_show_triggers | 702986
Com_show_variables | 648
Com_show_warnings | 15321
Com_show_create_user | 0
Com_shutdown | 0
Com_replica_start | 0
Com_slave_start | 0
Com_replica_stop | 0
Com_slave_stop | 0
Com_group_replication_start | 0
Com_group_replication_stop | 0
Com_stmt_execute | 0
Com_stmt_close | 0
Com_stmt_fetch | 0
Com_stmt_prepare | 0
Com_stmt_reset | 0
Com_stmt_send_long_data | 0
Com_truncate | 0
Com_uninstall_component | 0
Com_uninstall_plugin | 0
Com_unlock_instance | 0
Com_unlock_tables | 13260
Com_update | 784832
Com_update_multi | 0
Com_xa_commit | 0
Com_xa_end | 0
Com_xa_prepare | 0
Com_xa_recover | 0
Com_xa_rollback | 0
Com_xa_start | 0
Com_awslambda | 0
Com_alter_system | 0
Com_unit_test | 0
Com_show_volume_status | 0
Com_stmt_reprepare | 0
Connection_errors_accept | 0
Connection_errors_internal | 0
Connection_errors_max_connections | 0
Connection_errors_peer_address | 0
Connection_errors_select | 0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap | 0
Connections | 2038910
Created_tmp_disk_tables | 883
Created_tmp_files | 19665
Created_tmp_tables | 3883565
Delayed_errors | 0
Delayed_insert_threads | 0
Delayed_writes | 0
Error_log_buffered_bytes | 10976
Error_log_buffered_events | 83
Error_log_expired_events | 0
Error_log_latest_write | 1709825235374115
Flush_commands | 3
Global_connection_memory | 0
Handler_commit | 61027839
Handler_delete | 265951
Handler_discover | 0
Handler_external_lock | 276839613
Handler_mrr_init | 0
Handler_prepare | 0
Handler_read_first | 28458052
Handler_read_key | 339781404
Handler_read_last | 175570
Handler_read_next | 1529321466
Handler_read_prev | 270240705
Handler_read_rnd | 22316541
Handler_read_rnd_next | 9158337706
Handler_rollback | 167214
Handler_savepoint | 0
Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0
Handler_update | 12175120
Handler_write | 60152987
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status | 
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status | 
Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status | 
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data | 194578
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data | 3187965952
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty | 143
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty | 2342912
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed | 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free | 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc | 110
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total | 194688
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd | 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead | 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted | 271281
Innodb_logical_read_ahead_page_count | 52828972
Innodb_aurora_average_batched_read_request_size | 7
Innodb_aurora_batched_read_requests | 1559793
Innodb_aurora_shm_batched_read_requests | 1559793
Innodb_aurora_shm_read_requests | 8253438
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests | 10672076159
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads | 20476583
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free | 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests | 20304459
Innodb_data_fsyncs | 0
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs | 0
Innodb_data_pending_reads | 0
Innodb_data_pending_writes | 0
Innodb_data_read | 335497510912
Innodb_data_reads | 11942
Innodb_data_writes | 13496
Innodb_data_written | 0
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written | 0
Innodb_dblwr_writes | 0
Innodb_log_waits | 0
Innodb_log_write_requests | 0
Innodb_log_writes | 0
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs | 0
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs | 0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes | 0
Innodb_os_log_written | 0
Innodb_page_size | 16384
Innodb_pages_created | 94967
Innodb_pages_read | 20477548
Innodb_pages_written | 0
Innodb_redo_log_enabled | ON
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits | 0
Innodb_row_lock_time | 159
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg | 5
Innodb_row_lock_time_max | 35
Innodb_row_lock_waits | 30
Innodb_rows_deleted | 24929
Innodb_rows_inserted | 1262274
Innodb_rows_read | 10694424554
Innodb_rows_updated | 746111
Innodb_system_rows_deleted | 252513
Innodb_system_rows_inserted | 283465
Innodb_system_rows_read | 318461192
Innodb_system_rows_updated | 347064
Innodb_sampled_pages_read | 0
Innodb_sampled_pages_skipped | 0
Innodb_num_open_files | 10
Innodb_truncated_status_writes | 0
Innodb_undo_tablespaces_total | 2
Innodb_undo_tablespaces_implicit | 2
Innodb_undo_tablespaces_explicit | 0
Innodb_undo_tablespaces_active | 2
Key_blocks_not_flushed | 0
Key_blocks_unused | 13396
Key_blocks_used | 0
Key_read_requests | 0
Key_reads | 0
Key_write_requests | 0
Key_writes | 0
Locked_connects | 0
Max_execution_time_exceeded | 0
Max_execution_time_set | 0
Max_execution_time_set_failed | 0
Max_used_connections | 130
Max_used_connections_time | 2024-03-05 17:00:54
Not_flushed_delayed_rows | 0
Ongoing_anonymous_transaction_count | 0
Open_files | 2
Open_streams | 0
Open_table_definitions | 20000
Open_tables | 6000
Opened_files | 2
Opened_table_definitions | 1170497
Opened_tables | 5899304
Performance_schema_accounts_lost | 0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost | 0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost | 0
Performance_schema_digest_lost | 0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost | 0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost | 0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost | 0
Performance_schema_hosts_lost | 0
Performance_schema_index_stat_lost | 0
Performance_schema_locker_lost | 0
Performance_schema_memory_classes_lost | 0
Performance_schema_metadata_lock_lost | 0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost | 0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost | 0
Performance_schema_nested_statement_lost | 0
Performance_schema_prepared_statements_lost | 0
Performance_schema_program_lost | 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost | 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost | 0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_longest_seen | 0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost | 0
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost | 0
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost | 0
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost | 0
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost | 0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost | 0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost | 0
Performance_schema_table_lock_stat_lost | 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost | 0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost | 0
Performance_schema_users_lost | 0
Prepared_stmt_count | 0
Queries | 75795920
Questions | 57100560
Secondary_engine_execution_count | 0
Select_full_join | 395827
Select_full_range_join | 2086
Select_range | 721284
Select_range_check | 29
Select_scan | 18416923
Slave_open_temp_tables | 0
Slow_launch_threads | 0
Slow_queries | 143
Sort_merge_passes | 1514
Sort_range | 0
Sort_rows | 25017607
Sort_scan | 6471447
Table_locks_immediate | 16141
Table_locks_waited | 0
Table_open_cache_hits | 131416357
Table_open_cache_misses | 5899816
Table_open_cache_overflows | 5882645
Tc_log_max_pages_used | 0
Tc_log_page_size | 0
Tc_log_page_waits | 0
Threads_cached | 1
Threads_connected | 17
Threads_created | 7
Threads_running | 2
Uptime | 176548
Uptime_since_flush_status | 176548
server_audit_active | OFF
server_audit_last_error | 
server_audit_writes_failed | 0
server_aurora_das_messages_missed | 0
server_aurora_das_messages_queued | 0
server_aurora_das_num_fatal_errors | 0
server_aurora_das_running | OFF
```

Result of `SHOW VARIABLES`:

```
Variable_name | Value
big_tables | OFF
bind_address | *
binlog_cache_size | 32768
binlog_checksum | CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates | OFF
binlog_encryption | OFF
binlog_error_action | ABORT_SERVER
binlog_expire_logs_seconds | 0
binlog_format | ROW
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay | 0
binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count | 0
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery | ON
binlog_max_flush_queue_time | 0
binlog_order_commits | ON
binlog_rotate_encryption_master_key_at_startup | OFF
binlog_row_event_max_size | 8192
binlog_row_image | FULL
binlog_row_metadata | MINIMAL
binlog_row_value_options | 
binlog_rows_query_log_events | OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size | 32768
binlog_transaction_compression | OFF
binlog_transaction_compression_level_zstd | 3
binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size | 25000
binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking | COMMIT_ORDER
block_encryption_mode | aes-128-ecb
bulk_insert_buffer_size | 8388608
check_proxy_users | OFF
completion_type | NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert | AUTO
connect_timeout | 10
connection_memory_chunk_size | 8912
connection_memory_limit | 18446744073709551615
cte_max_recursion_depth | 1000
datadir | /rdsdbdata/db/
default_storage_engine | InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine | InnoDB
default_week_format | 0
delay_key_write | ON
delayed_insert_limit | 100
delayed_insert_timeout | 300
delayed_queue_size | 1000
disabled_storage_engines | 
div_precision_increment | 4
end_markers_in_json | OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency | OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit | 200
error_count | 0
event_scheduler | ON
expire_logs_days | 0
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp | ON
flush | OFF
flush_time | 0
foreign_key_checks | ON
ft_boolean_syntax | "+ -><()~*:""""&|"
ft_max_word_len | 84
ft_min_word_len | 4
ft_query_expansion_limit | 20
ft_stopword_file | (built-in)
generated_random_password_length | 20
global_connection_memory_limit | 18446744073709551615
global_connection_memory_tracking | OFF
group_concat_max_len | 1024
group_replication_consistency | EVENTUAL
gtid_executed | 
gtid_executed_compression_period | 0
gtid_mode | OFF_PERMISSIVE
gtid_next | AUTOMATIC
gtid_owned | 
gtid_purged | 
have_compress | YES
have_dynamic_loading | YES
have_geometry | YES
have_openssl | YES
have_profiling | YES
have_query_cache | NO
have_rtree_keys | YES
have_ssl | YES
have_statement_timeout | YES
have_symlink | DISABLED
histogram_generation_max_mem_size | 20000000
host_cache_size | 328
hostname | ip-172-27-1-235
identity | 0
immediate_server_version | 999999
information_schema_stats_expiry | 86400
innodb_adaptive_flushing | ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm | 10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index | OFF
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts | 8
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay | 150000
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval | 5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock | OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog | OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl | OFF
innodb_api_trx_level | 0
innodb_aurora_enable_auto_akp | OFF
innodb_aurora_max_partitions_for_range | 0
innodb_autoextend_increment | 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode | 2
innodb_btr_prefetch_perf_optimization | ON
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size | 1594884096
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now | OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct | 25
innodb_buffer_pool_filename | ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file | ON
innodb_buffer_pool_instances | 2
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort | OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup | OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now | OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size | 3189768192
innodb_change_buffer_max_size | 25
innodb_change_buffering | none
innodb_checksum_algorithm | none
innodb_cleanup_temp_tablespaces_in_background | ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled | OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency | 0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct | 5
innodb_compression_level | 6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max | 50
innodb_concurrency_tickets | 5000
innodb_data_file_path | ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir | 
innodb_ddl_buffer_size | 1048576
innodb_ddl_threads | 4
innodb_deadlock_detect | ON
innodb_dedicated_server | OFF
innodb_default_row_format | dynamic
innodb_directories | 
innodb_disable_shm_reads | OFF
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache | OFF
innodb_doublewrite | OFF
innodb_doublewrite_batch_size | 0
innodb_doublewrite_dir | 
innodb_doublewrite_files | 0
innodb_doublewrite_pages | 0
innodb_extend_and_initialize | OFF
innodb_fast_shutdown | 1
innodb_file_per_table | OFF
innodb_fill_factor | 100
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit | 1
innodb_flush_method | O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors | 0
innodb_flush_sync | ON
innodb_flushing_avg_loops | 30
innodb_force_load_corrupted | OFF
innodb_force_recovery | 0
innodb_fsync_threshold | 0
innodb_ft_aux_table | 
innodb_ft_cache_size | 8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print | OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword | ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size | 84
innodb_ft_min_token_size | 3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize | 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit | 2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table | 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree | 2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size | 640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table | 
innodb_idle_flush_pct | 100
innodb_io_capacity | 200
innodb_io_capacity_max | 2000
innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 50
innodb_log_buffer_size | 16777216
innodb_log_checksums | ON
innodb_log_compressed_pages | ON
innodb_log_file_size | 50331648
innodb_log_files_in_group | 2
innodb_log_group_home_dir | ./
innodb_log_spin_cpu_abs_lwm | 80
innodb_log_spin_cpu_pct_hwm | 50
innodb_log_vdl_improved_callback | ON
innodb_log_wait_for_flush_spin_hwm | 400
innodb_log_write_ahead_size | 8192
innodb_log_writer_threads | ON
innodb_lru_scan_depth | 1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct | 90.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm | 10.000000
innodb_max_purge_lag | 0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay | 0
innodb_max_undo_log_size | 1073741824
innodb_monitor_disable | 
innodb_monitor_enable | 
innodb_monitor_reset | 
innodb_monitor_reset_all | 
innodb_old_blocks_pct | 37
innodb_old_blocks_time | 1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size | 134217728
innodb_open_files | 300
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only | OFF
innodb_page_cleaners | 2
innodb_page_size | 16384
innodb_parallel_read_threads | 4
innodb_print_all_deadlocks | OFF
innodb_print_ddl_logs | OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size | 600
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency | 128
innodb_purge_threads | 1
innodb_random_read_ahead | OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold | 56
innodb_read_io_threads | 1
innodb_read_only | OFF
innodb_redo_log_archive_dirs | 
innodb_redo_log_encrypt | OFF
innodb_replication_delay | 0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF
innodb_rollback_segments | 128
innodb_segment_reserve_factor | 12.500000
innodb_shared_buffer_pool_uses_huge_pages | ON
innodb_sort_buffer_size | 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay | 6
innodb_spin_wait_pause_multiplier | 50
innodb_stats_auto_recalc | ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked | OFF
innodb_stats_method | nulls_equal
innodb_stats_notify_change | OFF
innodb_stats_on_metadata | OFF
innodb_stats_persistent | ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages | 20
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages | 8
innodb_status_output | OFF
innodb_status_output_locks | OFF
innodb_strict_mode | ON
innodb_sync_array_size | 1
innodb_sync_spin_loops | 30
innodb_table_locks | ON
innodb_temp_data_file_path | ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir | ./
innodb_thread_concurrency | 0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay | 10000
innodb_tmpdir | 
innodb_trx_write_next_max_trx_id | ON
innodb_undo_directory | ./
innodb_undo_log_encrypt | OFF
innodb_undo_log_truncate | OFF
innodb_undo_tablespaces | 2
innodb_use_fdatasync | OFF
innodb_use_native_aio | OFF
innodb_validate_tablespace_paths | OFF
innodb_version | 8.0.28
innodb_write_io_threads | 4
insert_id | 0
interactive_timeout | 28800
internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine | TempTable
join_buffer_size | 262144
keep_files_on_create | OFF
key_buffer_size | 16777216
key_cache_age_threshold | 300
key_cache_block_size | 1024
key_cache_division_limit | 100
keyring_operations | ON
large_files_support | ON
large_page_size | 0
large_pages | OFF
last_insert_id | 0
local_infile | ON
lock_wait_timeout | 31536000
locked_in_memory | OFF
log_bin | OFF
log_bin_basename | 
log_bin_index | 
log_bin_trust_function_creators | ON
log_bin_use_v1_row_events | OFF
log_error | /rdsdbdata/log/error/mysql-error.log
log_error_services | log_filter_internal; log_sink_internal
log_error_suppression_list | 
log_error_verbosity | 3
log_output | FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes | OFF
log_raw | OFF
log_replica_updates | ON
log_slave_updates | ON
log_slow_admin_statements | OFF
log_slow_extra | OFF
log_slow_replica_statements | OFF
log_slow_slave_statements | OFF
log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog | ON
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes | 0
log_timestamps | UTC
long_query_time | 10.000000
low_priority_updates | OFF
lower_case_file_system | OFF
lower_case_table_names | 0
master_info_repository | TABLE
master_verify_checksum | OFF
max_allowed_packet | 67108864
max_binlog_cache_size | 18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size | 134217728
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size | 18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors | 100
max_connections | 200
max_delayed_threads | 20
max_digest_length | 1024
max_error_count | 1024
max_execution_time | 0
max_heap_table_size | 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads | 20
max_join_size | 18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data | 4096
max_points_in_geometry | 65536
max_prepared_stmt_count | 16382
max_relay_log_size | 0
max_seeks_for_key | 18446744073709551615
max_sort_length | 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth | 0
max_user_connections | 0
max_write_lock_count | 18446744073709551615
min_examined_row_limit | 0
myisam_data_pointer_size | 6
myisam_max_sort_file_size | 9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size | 18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options | OFF
myisam_repair_threads | 1
myisam_sort_buffer_size | 8388608
myisam_stats_method | nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap | OFF
net_buffer_length | 16384
net_read_timeout | 30
net_retry_count | 10
net_write_timeout | 60
ngram_token_size | 2
offline_mode | OFF
old | OFF
old_alter_table | OFF
open_files_limit | 1048576
optimizer_prune_level | 1
optimizer_search_depth | 62
optimizer_switch | "index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=off,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on,use_invisible_indexes=off,skip_scan=on,hash_join=on,subquery_to_derived=off,prefer_ordering_index=on,hypergraph_optimizer=off,derived_condition_pushdown=on"
optimizer_trace | "enabled=off,one_line=off"
optimizer_trace_features | "greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on"
optimizer_trace_limit | 1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size | 1048576
optimizer_trace_offset | -1
original_commit_timestamp | 36028797018963968
original_server_version | 999999
parser_max_mem_size | 18446744073709551615
partial_revokes | OFF
performance_schema | OFF
performance_schema__auto__ | ON
performance_schema_accounts_size | 0
performance_schema_digests_size | 0
performance_schema_error_size | 5057
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size | 0
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size | 0
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size | 0
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size | 0
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size | 0
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size | 0
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size | 0
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size | 0
performance_schema_hosts_size | 0
performance_schema_max_cond_classes | 0
performance_schema_max_cond_instances | 0
performance_schema_max_digest_length | 0
performance_schema_max_digest_sample_age | 60
performance_schema_max_file_classes | 0
performance_schema_max_file_handles | 0
performance_schema_max_file_instances | 0
performance_schema_max_index_stat | 0
performance_schema_max_memory_classes | 0
performance_schema_max_metadata_locks | 0
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes | 0
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances | 0
performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances | 0
performance_schema_max_program_instances | 0
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes | 0
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances | 0
performance_schema_max_socket_classes | 0
performance_schema_max_socket_instances | 0
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length | 0
performance_schema_max_stage_classes | 0
performance_schema_max_statement_classes | 0
performance_schema_max_statement_stack | 0
performance_schema_max_table_handles | 0
performance_schema_max_table_instances | 0
performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat | 0
performance_schema_max_thread_classes | 0
performance_schema_max_thread_instances | 0
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size | 0
performance_schema_setup_actors_size | 0
performance_schema_setup_objects_size | 0
performance_schema_show_processlist | OFF
performance_schema_users_size | 0
persist_only_admin_x509_subject | 
persisted_globals_load | ON
pid_file | /rdsdbdata/log/mysql-3306.pid
port | 3306
preload_buffer_size | 32768
print_identified_with_as_hex | OFF
profiling | OFF
profiling_history_size | 15
protocol_compression_algorithms | "zlib,zstd,uncompressed"
protocol_version | 10
proxy_user | 
query_alloc_block_size | 8192
query_prealloc_size | 8192
rand_seed1 | 0
rand_seed2 | 0
range_alloc_block_size | 4096
range_optimizer_max_mem_size | 8388608
rbr_exec_mode | STRICT
read_buffer_size | 262144
read_only | OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size | 524288
regexp_stack_limit | 8000000
regexp_time_limit | 32
replication_optimize_for_static_plugin_config | OFF
replication_sender_observe_commit_only | OFF
require_row_format | OFF
require_secure_transport | OFF
resultset_metadata | FULL
rpl_read_size | 5242880
rpl_stop_replica_timeout | 31536000
rpl_stop_slave_timeout | 31536000
schema_definition_cache | 400
secondary_engine_cost_threshold | 100000.000000
select_into_buffer_size | 131072
select_into_disk_sync | OFF
select_into_disk_sync_delay | 0
session_track_gtids | OFF
session_track_schema | ON
session_track_state_change | OFF
session_track_transaction_info | OFF
sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys | ON
sha256_password_private_key_path | private_key.pem
sha256_password_proxy_users | OFF
sha256_password_public_key_path | public_key.pem
show_create_table_skip_secondary_engine | OFF
show_create_table_verbosity | OFF
show_old_temporals | OFF
skip_external_locking | ON
skip_name_resolve | ON
skip_networking | OFF
skip_replica_start | ON
skip_show_database | OFF
skip_slave_start | ON
slave_allow_batching | OFF
slave_checkpoint_group | 512
slave_checkpoint_period | 300
slave_compressed_protocol | OFF
slave_exec_mode | STRICT
slave_max_allowed_packet | 1073741824
slave_net_timeout | 60
slave_parallel_type | LOGICAL_CLOCK
slave_parallel_workers | 4
slave_pending_jobs_size_max | 134217728
slave_preserve_commit_order | ON
slave_rows_search_algorithms | "INDEX_SCAN , HASH_SCAN"
slave_skip_errors | OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum | ON
slave_transaction_retries | 10
slave_type_conversions | 
slow_launch_time | 2
socket | /tmp/mysql.sock
sort_buffer_size | 2097152
source_verify_checksum | OFF
sql_auto_is_null | OFF
sql_big_selects | ON
sql_buffer_result | OFF
sql_log_bin | ON
sql_log_off | OFF
sql_notes | ON
sql_quote_show_create | ON
sql_replica_skip_counter | 0
sql_require_primary_key | OFF
sql_safe_updates | OFF
sql_select_limit | 18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter | 0
stored_program_cache | 256
stored_program_definition_cache | 256
super_read_only | OFF
sync_binlog | 1
sync_master_info | 10000
sync_relay_log | 10000
sync_relay_log_info | 10000
sync_source_info | 10000
table_definition_cache | 20000
table_encryption_privilege_check | OFF
table_open_cache | 6000
table_open_cache_instances | 4
tablespace_definition_cache | 400
temptable_max_mmap | 1073741824
temptable_max_ram | 16777216
temptable_use_mmap | ON
terminology_use_previous | NONE
thread_cache_size | 4
thread_handling | thread-pools
thread_stack | 262144
tmp_table_size | 16777216
transaction_alloc_block_size | 8192
transaction_allow_batching | OFF
transaction_isolation | REPEATABLE-READ
transaction_prealloc_size | 4096
transaction_read_only | OFF
transaction_write_set_extraction | XXHASH64
unique_checks | ON
updatable_views_with_limit | YES
use_secondary_engine | ON
version | 8.0.28
wait_timeout | 28800
warning_count | 0
windowing_use_high_precision | ON
```

Result of `SELECT count(*)  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`:

```
count(*)
350963
```

Result of `SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables LIMIT 100000`

```
COUNT(*),sum(data_length),sum(index_length),sum(data_free)
350963,147484688384,15894839296,527753445113856
```

Result of `SELECT 'SLEEPING time use', COUNT(*),SUM(time) FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE command="Sleep"`

```
SLEEPING time use,COUNT(*),SUM(time)
SLEEPING time use,9,7639
```

AWS RSD instance: **t3.large**

Comment: Are you using `ENGINE=InnoDB` for the tables?  What are the values of `max_connections` and `Max_used_connections`?  Better yet, please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` and `SHOW VARIABLES;` so I can do a more thorough analysis of the many settings and metrics that interact with each other.  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: Max_used_connections=130, max_connections=200. I found out that the default values of table_open_cache and table_definition_cache in RDS are 6000 and 20000. I set those parameters as default but in STATUS Opened_tables is still very high and increasing.

Comment: Divide `Opened_tables` by `Uptime` to get opened per second.  20/hour to 50/second is typical.  There are lots of other STATUS values of interest.

Comment: I added the result of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`. Dividing opened tables by uptime I get 33/second.

Comment: Need SHOW VARIABLES, too.

Comment: Added result of SHOW VARIABLES. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Michele  Could you post your A) AWS RDS instance type in the question,  B) TEXT results of SHOW COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables: C)   TEXT results of  
SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables
LIMIT 100000; D) SELECT 'SLEEPING time use', 
COUNT(*),SUM(time)  
FROM information_schema.processlist 
WHERE 
command="Sleep"; 
 analysis is in process of your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES. Thanks

Comment: I have added the requested query results. Let me know if you need anything else. Thank you!

Comment: @Michele  Thank you for the additional information posted a couple hours ago.  The sum of data, index, data_free indicates you have been running the application for a while and never OPTIMIZE'd any TABLE to manage data_free (likely when rows are added to a table).  Running the sleeping query about 4 PM your local time would be interesting to see the results of Sleeping count and sum of TIME.  See Answers for suggestions for some immediate relief.  Please view profile and get in touch.

Comment: @Michele,  I see you are not using INNODB_file_per_table which could make management of your data_free space used more reasonable.  When you have time, let's talk about this aspect of your MySQL instance for 10 minutes.  We should also review the Dedicated/Shared plan you have with AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your Parameters Group on AWS RDS

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=16384  # from 512K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 51,875.
table_open_cache_instances=2  # from 4 because you only have 2 vCPU's.
table_definition_cache=50000  # from 20000 to support 2hrs RPhr of 23,868.
table_open_cache=140000  # from 6000 to support opened_tables RPhr of 120294.
innodb_open_files=140000  # from 300 - best practice EQUAL to table_open_cache.
```

Because some of these are STATIC variables, stop/start will be required.  There are many more opportunities to improve performance, including a host with more RAM and CPU's to complete requests faster and get out of the tx.xxx instance type which was meant for development and low volume activity.

Comment: @michele Were the suggestions applied?  Is your perceived system performance better/worse?